# Display images from SQLite to a column in QTableView

Tags: c++, qt

I stacked in a problem which is displaying images in each row in photo's column from SQLite Database

produits.cpp

```
    void produits::on_pushButton_4_clicked()
{
    login conn3;
    QSqlQueryModel * modal3=new QSqlQueryModel();

    conn3.connOpen();
    QSqlQuery* qry=new QSqlQuery(conn3.mydb);

    qry->prepare("select * from produits");

    qry->exec();
    modal3->setQuery(*qry);
    ui->tableView->setModel(modal3);
    conn3.connClose();

    qDebug() << (modal3->rowCount());
}
```

Comment: same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65612312/qsqltablemodel-display-images-from-sql-query-saved-as-blob ?

Comment: 1) The solution depends on the way you stores the images, so how do I store the images? Do I use a specific format for example base64 ?, 2) I could share the database (the .db file)